# Distribution of $\| W_t \|^2_{L^2([0,T])}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Motivation: consider the SDE

$$dX_t = b(X_t) dt + \sqrt{\varepsilon} dW_t. \tag1$$

Consider the action, defined by

$$S(\phi)=\int_0^T |\phi'(t)-b(\phi(t))|^2 dt$$

if $\phi \in H^1([0,T])$ and $+\infty$ otherwise.

If $\phi$ is a sample path of $(1)$, then we can rearrange to see that $S(\phi)=\varepsilon \| W_t \|^2_{L^2([0,T])}$, where $W_t$ is the particular Brownian motion which drives $\phi$. I think this implies that the probability density of the paths is $\phi \mapsto f_\varepsilon(S(\phi))$ where $f_\varepsilon$ is the probability density for $\varepsilon \| W_t \|^2_{L^2([0,T])}$.

So I get the question: what are the properties of the distribution of $\| W_t \|^2_{L^2([0,T])}$?

The one thing that I think I have correctly derived is:

$$\mathbb{E} \left ( \| W_t \|^2_{L^2([0,T])} \right ) = \mathbb{E} \left ( \int_0^T W_t^2 dt \right )= \int_0^T \mathbb{E} \left ( W_t^2 \right ) dt = \int_0^T t dt = T^2/2.$$

Any information about the distribution of this quantity, for instance how to compute its variance, would be appreciated.

Edit: Nate Eldredge has pointed out that my motivation, while intuitive, does not really work when treated formally as written, because $S(\phi)=+\infty$ with probability $1$. So I would also be interested in some description, formal or informal, of the extent to which $S$ and the distribution of paths of (1) are connected.

Comment: A sample path of a solution of (1) is nowhere differentiable, so what does $\phi'$ mean?

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point, let me make an edit. (There is an explanation.)

Comment: It's not better the way you have it.  An element of $H^1([0,1])$ is absolutely continuous and hence almost everywhere differentiable, so a sample path of $X_t$ is not in $H^1([0,1])$, and strictly speaking your action is $+\infty$ almost surely.  I understand what you mean at an informal level, but to have it actually make sense you have to reformulate it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Interesting; do you know how the reformulation looks? In particular, do you know how the distribution of paths of (1) relates (perhaps only asymptotically) to $S$?

Comment: It's a bit too large a subject to discuss here, but basically this is the issue faced in making the Feynman path integral rigorous.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that I fixed a mistake in my answer.  I think it is correct now, I checked it against some numerical simulations.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the variance by the following trick:
$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^T W_t^2\,dt\right)^2\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T W_t^2\,dt \int_0^T W_s^2\,ds\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T \int_0^T W_t^2 W_s^2 \,dt\,ds\right] \\
&= \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[W_t^2 W_s^2]\,dt\,ds.
\end{align*}$$
Now for $s \le t$, we can write $W_t = W_s + (W_t - W_s)$ and so we have $$W_t^2 W_s^2 = (W_t - W_s)^2 W_s^2 + 2 (W_t - W_s) W_s^3 + W_s^4.$$
Taking expectations and using independence of increments (and noting that the case $s \ge t$ is symmetric),
$$\mathbb{E}[W_t^2 W_s^2] = \begin{cases} (t-s) s + 3 s^2, & s \le t \\ (s-t) t + 3 t^2, & s \ge t \end{cases}$$
So we end up with
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^T W_t^2\,dt\right)^2\right]  &= \int_0^T \int_0^t ((t-s) s + 3 s^2)\,ds\,dt + \int_0^T \int_t^T ((s-t) t + 3 t^2)\,ds\,dt \\ &= \frac{7}{12} T^4\end{align*}$$

This means the variance is $\frac{7}{12} T^4 - \frac{1}{4} T^4 = \frac{1}{3} T^4$.  I think you could get higher moments with a similar approach.

I don't know of a closed form for the density function but there are certainly asymptotics for the probability of being very large or very small.  A phrase to look for is "quadratic functionals of Brownian motion" or "Wiener chaos of order 2".

For example, in

> Wenbo V. Li, Small ball probabilities for Gaussian Markov processes under the $L^p$-norm,
>   Stochastic Process. Appl. 92 (2001), no. 1, 87–102.

Lemma 2.3 implies the statement:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \epsilon \log \mathbb{P}\left(\int_0^1 W_t^2\,dt < \epsilon\right) = -\frac{1}{8}.$$