# Finding $E[W]$ and $E[W^2]$, where $W = \int_{t=0}^T B_s$ $ds$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I'm trying to find a)$E[W]$ and b) $E[W^2]$, where $W_t = \int_{t=0}^T B_s$ $ds$ ($B_s$ denotes a Brownian motion).

In addition, I'd like to find $E[Z_sZ_t]$,  where $Z_t = \int_0^t B_s^2$$ ds$

$E[W] = 0$ since $B_s$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,s)$

$E[W^2] = \int_0^t \int_0^t E[W_sW_t] ds$ $dt $

$= \int_0^t \int_0^t $min$(s,t)ds$ $dt =\int_0^t\int_0^t sdsdt + \int_0^t \int_0^t tdsdt = \int_0^t \frac{t^2}{2}dt + \int_0^t (t-t^2)dt = \frac{t^3}{3}$

As for finding $E[Z_sZ_t]$, I'm stuck.

Comment: Please add the definition of $Z_t$ to your question (and/or correct several typos so that we don't have to guess what you might mean)...

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't realize I missed that.

Comment: Well, the definition $Z_t = \int_{t=0}^T B_s^2 \, ds$ doesn't make sense. Do you mean $Z_t = \int_t^T B_s^2 \, ds$?

Comment: My bounds are off here. I need to look at this for a while. I'm using a book and a paper, they use different notations.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn $Z_s Z_t$ into a double integral just like you did with $W^2$:

$$Z_s Z_t = \int_0^s \int_0^t B_u^2 B_r^2 dr du.$$

After a Fubini theorem, you can follow the approach in [Distribution of $\| W_t \|^2_{L^2([0,T])}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235983/distribution-of-w-t-2-l20-t), you get the expectation of the integrand, and then the rest of the problem is calculus.

Comment: But that's what the OP already did, isn't it? (S)He already calculated $\mathbb{E}(W)$ and $\mathbb{E}(W^2)$.

Comment: @saz Oh, you're right. In that case the problem they're stuck on is *actually* the problem in my link.